# When should I use getInitialState in a React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that toggles a `className` when the component is clicked

```js
var Foo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {className: ''}
  },

  render: function(){
    var className = 'bar ' + this.state.className
    return React.createElement('div', {className: className, onClick: this.onClick})
  },

  onClick: function() {
    this.setState({className: 'baz'})
  }
});
```

It works fine, but when I am rendering the app server side, I get the following error

```
Warning: getInitialState was defined on a component, a plain JavaScript class.
This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass.
Did you mean to define a state property instead?
```

My build step is setup like so

```js
var Foo = require('./Foo');
var factory = React.createFactory(Foo);
module.exports = React.renderToString(factory({}));
```

Why is what I am doing wrong, and how should it be done?

Comment: That message comes up if you're using plain ES6 classes. What's your build process doing? See here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es6-classes

Comment: I am not using ES6 classes - I will the question with my build example, but its more or less just renderToString

Comment: Are you exporting the `Foo` (it's not in your example). I just created a tiny test project locally that works fine and does not produce the error. My demo app is using React 0.13. Output: `<div class="bar " data-reactid=".3usffrojk0" data-react-checksum="-1133309707"></div>`

Comment: @WiredPrairie yeah, im exporting foo. The actual app is obviously more complicated, I the error just comes form that one component.

Comment: I think the bug is caused by something else then that you haven't posted. There isn't anything wrong with the code you posted that I can see (and as I mentioned, I tried it locally).

Comment: i'll try to reduce the actual app down to something smaller that generates the error. thanks for your help!

Comment: Checkout the `classnames` [lib](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) (former `classset`) to do this. There is IMO little need for setting initial state on small components. You just make `render()` handle if the property is null.
My suggestion using classnames:
    render: function(){
        var classes = {
            'bar': true,
            'baz': !!this.state.clicked
        }
        return React.createElement('div', {className: ClassSet(className), onClick: this.onClick})
    },
    onClick: function() {
       this.setState({clicked: true})
    }
Hence no need for `getInitialState`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps, but while using fluxible, this is the syntax i used with JSX as part of require component

```
var app = new Fluxible({
  component: React.createFactory(require('./Components/startup.react.jsx'))
});
```

Comment: it's not working for me althought it seems like a solution?